# Replacing the first <br /> tag in MySQL column

Tags: mysql, replace

There is some text column containing some value. E.g.

```
<ul>
<li>bla bla&nbsp;bla bla bla&nbsp;bla bla bla.</li>
<li>bla bla&nbsp;bla bla bla&nbsp;bla bla bla.</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<br />• text text text.
<br />• text text text.
<br />
```

How do I remove only the first `<br/>` tag in each record that begins with it?

Comment: replace all `<br />` or Just the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove the 1st `<br />` if the record **starts** with `<br />`:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = SUBSTRING(field, 7)
WHERE LEFT(field, 6) = '<br />'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the mysql [trim function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
TRIM(LEADING '<br />' FROM column_name)
```

example:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '<br />' FROM doyouknow) as doyouknow FROM actors;
```

This will remove the "<br />" from the start of doyouknow if it is there or do nothing. This will not change the data in your database like an update query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN doyouknow LIKE '<br />%' THEN SUBSTRING(doyouknow, 7) ELSE doyouknow END,
  othercol1,
  othercol
FROM..
```

If you need to update the data in the table, use this

```
UPDATE TBL
SET doyouknow =
  CASE WHEN doyouknow LIKE '<br />%' THEN SUBSTRING(doyouknow, 7) ELSE doyouknow END,
```